# Horizontal scroll on <ul> <li>

Tags: html, css

I would like to create quick replies like in Facebook Messenger. You can see the result in the picture below :
[image]

Here is the .css and the HTML I used :

```css
.quick_replies {
  display: inline;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border: solid 2px #86BB71;
}
```

```html
<ul style="white-space:nowrap;margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 1</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 2</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 3</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 4</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 5</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 6</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 3</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 7</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 8</li>
</ul>
```

**How can I create an Horizontal Scroll with these quick replies and don't let them enlarge the container div ?**

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow: auto;` to the `ul`?

Comment: on that ul just add `scroll: auto;`

Answer (score 5):

you need to add a width and `overflow:auto` (or `overflow:scroll`) to your `ul`:

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.quick_replies {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border: solid 2px #86BB71;
}
```

```html
<ul style="white-space:nowrap;margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 1</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 2</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 3</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 4</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 5</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 6</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 3</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 7</li>
  <li class="quick_replies">Réponse 8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's seems great Thanks ! But it doesn't keep the height ... ? My quick replies seems to be shorter and cut

Comment: See update - it's because you chose inline for your li - you need inline-block, otherwise it ignores some styles like certain sides of padding